# kustomize build failure in GitLab pipelines

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, kustomize

kustomize build is failing with GitLab pipelines but working locally.

`kustomize build .`

Kustomize version: 5.2.1 (locally and on GitLab runner)

The kustomization.yaml file

```
    apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Kustomization
    
    namespace: namespace
    
    namePrefix: app-name
    
    images:
      - name: app-image
        newName: image_name
        newTag: image_tag
    
    resources:
      - https://gitlab.link/group_name/app_name//apps/app_one/base?ref=master    ## This does not work 
    
    resources:             ## This works fine
      - ../../base
```

What I have tried:

- Updating git version
- Updating Kustomize version
- Making sure git credentials are valid
- Logging into git before running kustomize build command (git config)
- With git:: in resources

Error message:

```
Error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from evalsymlink failure on Error: accumulating resources: accumulating resources from 'https://gitlab.link/group_name/app_name//apps/app_one/base?ref=master': MalformedYAMLError: yaml: line 36: mapping values are not allowed in this context in File: https://gitlab.link/group_name/app_name//apps/app_one/base?ref=master
```

This works when I run the kustomize build command locally with exakt same kustomization.yaml file

Any ideas on what's wrong here?
I appreciate all help / tips.

Comment: We'd need a bit more information to have the full picture of your current setup. Is the Kustomize file in the same repo as the CI pipeline or are you trying to execute it from a different project?

Comment: What's line 36 in the referenced file? Sounds like a tall content issue. Have you tried a curl on the file in Gitlab pipeline to display what Kustomize sees from the pipeline?

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I got it to work after all, added the answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding this before kustomize build command:

```
- git config --global url."https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@url.com".insteadOf https://url.com
```